# libjingle googletalk client

Tags: android, libjingle, google-talk

I've a google talk client based on libjingle and called from android, every time I try to login this is all I get

```
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Dec 4 21:38:02 2012
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="A98AA8981D6845B2" version="1.0"
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Dec 4 21:38:02 2012
   <stream:features>
     <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">
       <required/>
     </starttls>
     <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
       <mechanism>
         X-GOOGLE-TOKEN
       </mechanism>
     </mechanisms>
   </stream:features>
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: sorry.the question is why is the login not going through even though the process seems to attempt to access googletalk?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you ever found the answer, but just in case you have not yet (and for others with the same problem)

Looking at the returned stanza, it appears you are trying to communicate with `GMail.com`. In my experience with LibJingle/XMPP/GoogleTalk, XMPP stanzas need to be sent to: `talk.google.com` and not `gmail.com` (or some other Google domain). `talk.google.com` is Google's XMPP service, and will forward messages to users in the Google Talk desktop application, as well as in browsers.

EDIT:
Also, I was looking around the latest LibJingle source code (I am not sure which code you are using), but it appears that they added code to specfically communicate with Google servers. I do not remember exactly which files, but it might be the LibJingle Plus files. If you are looking to do more than just messaging, you might want to look around there.